# Aac encoder using mediacodec was initialized with one channel but outputs as two channels

Tags: android, audio, aac, android-mediacodec

The aac decoder is initialized as below:

```
MediaFormat outfmt = new MediaFormat();
outfmt.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm");
outfmt.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, mAudioProfile);
mSampleRate = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE);
outfmt.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, mSampleRate);
mChannels = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT);
outfmt.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, mChannels);
outfmt.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 64000);
audioEncoder.configure(outfmt, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
            audioEncoder.start();
```

But the encoder behaviors different on two devices.

One outputs normal presentation:
64000 128000 192000 256000 320000

Another outputs as two channels:
64000 64000 128000 128000 192000 192000 256000 256000 320000 320000

And the format extracted using MediaExtractor is different on two devices:

the normal one is
    {max-input-size=1572864, aac-profile=2,
    csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=2,capacity=2], sample-rate=16000,
    durationUs=8640000, channel-count=1, mime=audio/mp4a-latm, isDMCMMExtractor=1}

The other is 
    {max-input-size=798, durationUs=8640000, channel-count=1, mime=audio/mp4a-latm,
    csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=2,capacity=2], sample-rate=16000}

So the original audio has one channel and the encoder is configured with one channel too.But the encoder outputs as in two channel way.

Does it matter with isDMCMMExtractor flag?

Help!Help!
@fadden

Comment: what devices are you using?

Comment: I'm using Xiaomi MI 3.I have found more details.When the encoder is fed with presentation 0, it outputs presentation 0 and 64000.When it is fed with presentation 64000, it outputs presentation 64000 and 128000, etc.But the encoder performs normal when it encodes buffer from AudioRecorder with presentionUs.They are initialized in the same way but perform very different.Very strange!

Comment: and what is the second device?

Comment: The second device is Samsung G7106.

Comment: Hi Marlon.Do you have any idea?

Comment: i think mstorsjo's answer is correct. try to use format after decoder, because different devices work differently and also it depends on android version

Answer (score 3):

First off, the question is very hard to understand - both of the listed MediaFormat contents show `channel-count=1`, so there's very little actual explanation of the issue itself, only an explanation of other surrounding details.

However - the software AAC decoder in some android versions (4.1 if I remember correctly, possibly 4.2 as well) will decode mono AAC into stereo - not sure if some of the hardware AAC decoders do the same. You can argue whether this is a bug or just unexpected behaviour, but it's something you have to live with. In the case that the decoder returns stereo data even though the input was mono, both stereo channels will have the same (mono) content.

So basically, you have to be prepared to handle this - either pass the actual format information from the decoder (not from MediaExtractor) to whoever is using the data (e.g. reconfigure the audio output to stereo), or be prepared to mix down stereo back into mono if you really need to have the output in mono format.

Comment: Yes,it looks very strange.It performs normal when it encodes buffer recorded by AudioRecorder which is initialized using mono format.Also it performs normal when decoding audio with two channels, but it outputs monotonic presentationUs, such as 0, 36550, 72332, etc.So my question is how to judge whether the decoder decode it to mono or stereo?Can I handle it by simply dropping the repeated presentation packet?

Comment: I must handle the abnormal situation but fear to affect the normal one's behavior.

Comment: If the decoder decodes it as stereo, you should be able to see the format in MediaFormat returned by `MediaCodec.getOutputFormat()` (after the `INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED` event). But you seem to be talking about the timestamps returned by the decoder, which would be a completely different issue. In that case, check what packets you actually get from `MediaExtractor` - are they the same as on the other, working device, or are they duplicated?

Comment: Thank you, mstorsjo.This is the key point.The decoder indeed decodes the mono to stereo and the mediaformat returned after the INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED event proves it.So I configure the encoder after the event and it works successfully.